# Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance in tiles

Tags: html, tiles

i am using tiles (2.0) for the first time. i wrote the following code in web.xml

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINTION_CONFIG</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.tiles.web.startup.TilesListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

I created tiles,xml in WEB-INF folder. when i deploy the project it gives an exception stating

```
Exception  **sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.apache.tiles.web.startup.TilesListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/digester/Rule**
```

I did not understand what is happening and why.

Answer (score 0):

You are obviously missing Commons Digester. Did you put all dependencies in your WEB-INF/lib directory?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still seeks the answer. apetrelli's solution worked fine for me. Import Commons Digester jar to your lib.